# Autofac resolve dependant services by name

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

Is it possible to register a single service that has dependencies that can change depending on a setting?

For instance

A `DBExecutor` requries a different `DBconnection` object depending which geographical region it is running under.

I've tried something like

```
builder.RegisterType<DbConnection>().Named<IDbConnection>("US")
builder.RegisterType<DbConnection>().Named<IDbConnection>("AU")
builder.RegisterType<SqlExecutor>().As<IDbExecutor>();
```

and I'd like to resolve the service with something like

```
var au = container.ResolveNamed<IDbExecutor>("AU");
var us = container.ResolveNamed<IDbExecutor>("US");
```

However this doesn't work because the `IDbExecutor` itself hasn't been registered with a key, and if I try a normal Resolve it wont work as it cannot create the dependent services.

Basically I just want an instance of of `IDbExecutor` with a `DBConnection` based upon a certain parameter.

I'm trying to do this in a more general sense so I'm trying to avoid any specific code where I can.

The current generic code I have that doesn't use keyed services looks like

```
var job = (IJob) lifetimeScope.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
```

where `JobType` is a class `Type` and depending on if this is possible the final version would look something like

```
 var job = (IJob) lifetimeScope.Resolve(bundle.JobDetail.JobType, bundle.JobDetail.JobDataMap["Region"]);
```

where `bundle.JobDetail.JobDataMap["Region"]` would return either `"AU"` or `"US"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to rig it to resolve a named `IDbExecutor` because you didn't register it as named. It's also probably not the best idea since it implies that `IDbExecutor` somehow "knows" about its dependencies, which it shouldn't - the *implementation* knows, but the interface/service doesn't - and shouldn't.

You can get something close to what you want by updating the `SqlExecutor` to use [the `IIndex<X,B>` relationship in Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html). Instead of taking just an `IDbConnection` in your constructor, take an `IIndex<string,IDbConnection>`.

When you need to get the connection, look it up from the indexed dictionary using the job type:

```
public class SqlExecutor
{
  private IIndex<string, IDbConnection> _connections;
  public SqlExecutor(IIndex<string, IDbConnection> connections)
  {
    this._connections = connections;
  }

  public void DoWork(string jobType)
  {
    var connection = this._connections[jobType];
    // do something with the connection
  }
}
```

Another way to do it would be to [create a delegate factory](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) for the `SqlExecutor` that takes in the job type and automatically picks the right named service. That's a bit more involved so [check out the documentation for an example](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html).